# Uncaught Error: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found

Tags: magento2, zoho

I am facing problem when implementing this https://github.com/maidmaid/zoho in magento2. rest all dependies are resolved but from composer it is not reading only GuzzleHttp\Client class and giving error "Uncaught Error: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found" in /vendor/Maidmaid/Zoho/Client.php on line 24

autoload_static.php define this

```
'GuzzleHttp\\' => 
        array (
            0 => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src',
        ),
```

and in autoload_psr4 defined this

```
'Maidmaid\\Zoho\\' => array($vendorDir . '/maidmaid/zoho/src'),
    'GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\' => array($vendorDir . '/guzzlehttp/psr7/src'),
    'GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\' => array($vendorDir . '/guzzlehttp/promises/src'),
    'GuzzleHttp\\' => array($vendorDir . '/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src'),
```

Please if anyone can help me in fixing this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to install Guzzle package using composer.

first go to your project directory and then install guzzle using this command

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below line

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'
```